# Recode and sum to NA when all values are NA in R

Tags: r, recode

I need to assign `NA` when all the columns are empty in summation for each `id`.

Here is how my sample dataset looks like;

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 i1 = c(1,NA,0),
                 i2 = c(1,NA,1),
                 i3 = c(1,NA,0),
                 total = c(3,0,1))

> df
  id i1 i2 i3 total
1  1  1  1  1     3
2  2 NA NA NA     0
3  3  0  1  0     1
```

For the second `id` the total should be `NA` instead of 0 because all the values are NA for the second id. How can I change the dataset to below?

```
  > df1
      id i1 i2 i3 total
    1  1  1  1  1     3
    2  2 NA NA NA     NA
    3  3  0  1  0     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a condition with `if_all` in `case_when` to return `NA` when all the column values are NA for a row or else do the `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(total = case_when(if_all(i1:i3,  is.na) ~ NA_real_,
        TRUE ~ rowSums(across(i1:i3), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
  id i1 i2 i3 total
1  1  1  1  1     3
2  2 NA NA NA    NA
3  3  0  1  0     1
```